# Can't reference drawable PNG in Java?

Tags: java, android, file, drawable

I have about 10 pictures in my drawable folder. But when referencing some of them in Java like this:

```
R.drawable.example
```

Only about 6 of the pictures show up when pressing CTRL+Space. If I try to reference some of the pictures, they don't show up in the CTRL+Space dialog box. If I try to type the filename manually, I get an error in my Java, as if they don't exist in my drawable folder.

Comment: projectright click -> refresh

Comment: @Zortkun I've done that many times. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Project > Clean.  Your `gen` folder should be deleted.  If it doesn't automatically get rebuilt, Refresh your project after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried right-clicking on your res folder within the Eclipse Package Explorer, selecting refresh, and then going to Project -> Clean,  and then rebuilding your project?

Comment: Cleaning then refreshing did it. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

check your imports at the top of the file.  Without samples, this is a guess, but PROBABLY there is:

`import Android.R`

but it should say:

`import myProject.R`

Comment: Yes, this one helped me, I was copying code from tutorials of official documentation.

Comment: thanks, i changed 
import android.R 
with 
import com.example.myAppName.
It work.

Answer (score 2):

Are there any uppercase letters in the image names? If so, switch them to lowercase, you can't use uppercase in image names.

Answer (score -1):

Faced the same issue what worked for me was doing the below

> **File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart**